# C# Windows Forms - outputting info to a textbox without crashing

Tags: c#, winforms

In a Windows Forms app, I am using Quartz.NET to run some tasks every few minutes. Previously, this application was a console application that was invoked based on a schedule but for various reasons this wasn't ideal - back then all debug info was outputted to the console.

In this version, I need a way to show the debug information for a job on the user's screen. My initial idea was a new form that is shown when a job is run, and all debug information is appended to a multiline textbox on that form. However, this doesn't work as most of the app seems to crash when I do this.

Any other ideas?

EDIT: Sorry for any confusion. This is what's called when a job executes:

```
    public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        RunJob jobForm = new RunJob();
        jobForm.Show();
        jobForm.JobLabel = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetString("Name");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            jobForm.WriteLine(i.ToString());
        }
        jobForm.Hide();
    }
```

And this is the contents of the 'RunJob' form:

```
public partial class RunJob : Form
    {
        public string JobLabel
        {
            get
            {
                return lblJobName.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                lblJobName.Text = value;
            }
        }

        public void WriteLine(string text)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        public RunJob()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

Basically, the RunJob window freezes when the text is being appended, when ideally it'd just add the text smoothly. I understand 'crash' was a very poor choice of word! My excuse is that it's early in the morning, ahem

Comment: can you show us your code and point where you think it is crashing?

Comment: This is very vague and open ended - you're not asking why it crashes you're asking for an application solution.

Comment: -1 for "it does not work" without showing any error, nor code.

Comment: why do u have  jobForm.Show(); and jobForm.Hide();  in the same function? i mean 'RunJob' will be visible for not even a second, what the use of this?

Comment: Because in the future, a fairly long proccess will run here - this is just me testing.

Comment: Add this to the WriteLine() method: textBox1.Update();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont see anything wrong in above code that could lead it to deadlock or whatever it is, except this line:     `jobForm.JobLabel = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetString("Name");`

what does this line does, there must be something wrong in this line, 
try putting some hard coded string instead of `context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetString("Name");` and tell me if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Job and UI form should obviously be at separate threads. Job thread should write to the form and then close it when unneeded.

Presuming you have an Action action that is invoked on UI thread:

```
public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
{
    RunJob jobForm;
    var name = context.JobDetail.JobDataMap.GetString("Name");
    action(()=> { jobForm = new RunJob(); jobForm.Show(); jobForm.JobLabel = name;});

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        var txt = i.ToString();
        action(()=>{ jobForm.WriteLine(txt); });
    }
    action(()=> { jobForm.Hide(); });
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I doubt he wants to create 100 forms.